# Expresso Store: Large quantity of items in cart gives PHP error

Tags: expresso-store

Getting a PHP error in Expresso Store if 35 products or more are in the cart.

```
Message: unserialize()[function.unserialize]: Error at offset 49148 of 49151 bytes
Filename: libraries/store_cart.php
Line Number: 900
```

Any ideas why this would happen? Tried recreating the issue and on the second time, the cart just empties when I add a 36th product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in our next upcoming release of Store.

If you need an immediate solution, edit your database and change the `contents` column in the `exp_store_carts` table from `TEXT` to `MEDIUMTEXT`. This will give you shopping carts more room to breathe.

When you install the next version of Store it will simply update this column type again so there is no issue with editing your database directly.